# Website root folder - PHP - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've recently set up a VPS server using 123-reg.co.uk

I have a number of sites to transfer to it that use Wordpress as a CMS service.

I 'include' worpress as follows:

```
require('/blog/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Which gives me access to predefined wordpress methods such as **get_page_by_title( 'home' )** which retrieves the page named 'home'.

Here's the issue, it looks like wordpress relies on an absolute path to further include the files it needs and I'm struggling to get it working.

Further information:

Wordpress is installed in a folder /blog/
It's included as follows:

```
define('PROJECT_ROOT', getcwd());
include PROJECT_ROOT . "/includes/header1.php";
```

which calls

```
include_once PROJECT_ROOT . "/includes/config.php";
require(PROJECT_ROOT .  '/blog/wp-blog-header.php');
```

The config PHP works fine as does the *initial* wordpress include.

wp-blog-header.php calls 'require_once( dirname(**FILE**) . '/wp-load.php' );'

Which seems to go to '/var/www/vhosts/websitename.co.uk/httpdocs/blog/wp-load.php' which looks right but which causes the site to fail with a generic error (500 internal server error).

Any ideas ?

EDIT: Apache error logs:

```
2016-08-16 17:57:04 Warning 86.182.179.139      mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds              Apache error
2016-08-16 17:57:04 Error   86.182.179.139      Premature end of script headers: index.php              Apache error
```

As requested by @gentlemanmax

Comment: Do you have access to your apche logs?  They will give you much better specifics on the error you're getting.

Comment: Changing permissions had no effect and there's no .htaccess file :(

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed? If so, have you tried disabling/removing them?

Comment: Only tinyMCE advanced but that shouldn't affect this

Comment: /blog/index.php & /blog/wp-login.php both also throw (unhelpful) errors

Comment: [check](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/500-internal-server-errors-when-accessing-dashboard)
and do test check index.php by writing <?php die("hello"); ?> on the first line

Comment: try to set paths like this:
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/wordpress');
define('WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/wp-content');

Comment: Have you tried raising the timeout in FcgidIOTimeout (see http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidiotimeout) to 90 or so?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the page you are accessing in a browser is one level above the `blog` dir where Wordpress is installed, try:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/blog/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

just need to run below command then it worked for me

```
a2enmod php7.2
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation which might help more.